# How are packages maintained in Ubuntu

Tags: package-management

Lets say I copy a .deb package to /tmp directory and install it (dpkg -i).

After a reboot should this package get loaded automatically ? Since /tmp directly gets wiped off I am wondering how the package is maintained after a reboot.

Comment: This depends on the package. Most of them are installed and integrated into the system, into folders susch as `/var`, `/etc/`, `/usr/share` etc. you might want to read here: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

Comment: Program.deb is like setup.exe
At least functionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .deb is nothing more then an archive, like a zip file.

"Installing" the .deb is nothing more then copying the files from the archive into the system + a few pre or post copy (installing) scripts / restarting / reloading configuration files + a tracking system.

Removing the archive, the .deb, does not un-install the package, so it does not matter if the .deb was downloaded and installed from /tmp or deleted after install.

See also this fedora link for how packaging management works. It is written for Fedora, but applies to most Linux OS (although Ubuntu uses apt)  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system